# How to draw a chart with nonlinear x-axis (logarithmic scale)?

Tags: charts, draw, flot

I am  trying to draw a Critical Power Chart like this:
[image]

The data I get is linear. One value for every second from 1 up to 18000. 
I have no clue how to teach flot to draw an non-linear x-axis. 
I tried to set custom ticks, but this seems to just have impact to the labels, not the line.

The x axis ticks will always be the same and don't need to be calculated:

```
[1s,5s,15s,30s,1m,2m,3m,5m,10m,20m30m,1h,2h,3h,5h]
```

Playground including tons of data: https://jsfiddle.net/ogeo2ygx/6/

Code:

```
$.plot($("#cpChart"), [{data: data,label: "Critical Power", labelBoxBorderColor: 0, color: '#cbcbcb',yaxis:1,lines: { show: true, fill: true } }], {
        xaxes: [{
            //here should be some Magic to Draw an nice Critical Power Chart
            tickFormatter: (t, v) => {
                return t + "s";
            }
        }],
        yaxes: [{
            alignTicksWithAxis: 1,
            position: "left",
            tickFormatter: (t, v) => {
                return t.toFixed(0) + " Watt"
            }
        }],
        legend: {
            position: 'sw',
            labelBoxBorderColor: 0
        },
        colors: ["#1ab394"],
        grid: {
            color: "#999999",
            clickable: true,
            tickColor: "#D4D4D4",
            borderWidth: 0,
            hoverable: true
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that (which is called [logarithmic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale)) with two steps:

1. Transform the x-axis values using the `Math.log` function (with a `+1` because the logarithm of zero is -infinity).
2. Define a custom `ticks` array with your ticks.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) for more information.
Relevant code:

```
xaxes: [{
    ticks: [[1, '1s'],[5, '5s'], [15, '15s'],[30, '30s'],[60, '1m'],[120, '2m'],[180, '3m'], [300, '5m'], [600, '10m'], [1200, '20m'], [1800, '30m'],[3600, '1h'], [7200, '2h'], [10800, '3h'], [18000, '5h']],
    transform: (x) => { return Math.log(1 + x); },
    inverseTransform: (x) => { return Math.exp(x) - 1; }
}],
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ogeo2ygx/8/

Comment: Thanks Raidri! Perfect!